# Proving $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$ using biconditionals, but I cannot seem to get the proof to work out.
\begin{align*}
x \in A \cap (B - C) & \iff x \in A \text{ and } x \in B - C \\
& \iff x \in A \text{ and } (x \in B \text{ and } x \not \in C) \\
& \iff (x \in A \text{ and } x \in B) \text{ and } (x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in C) \\
& \iff x \in A \cap B \text{ and } x \in A - C \\
& \iff x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A-C).
\end{align*}
I cannot figure out how to get from $(A \cap B) \cap (A - C)$ to $(A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**
$(x \in A \text{ and } x \in B) \text{ and } (x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in C)\\
\iff (x \in A \text{ and } x \in B) \text{ and } (x\in A \text{ and }x \not\in A \cap C)$

Comment: The forward implication makes sense, but why is it the case that $x \not \in A \cap C$ implies $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$? We could instead have, for example, $x \in C$ and $x \not \in A$.

Comment: Hmmm, but we already have $x \in A$ from the first parenthesis, so we must have $x \not \in C$ if $x \not \in A \cap C$. Got it -- thank you!

Comment: I have edited my answer to avoid confusion!

Comment: This is a helpful intermediary step. I appreciate it! (It won't let me accept an answer yet, but I will in just a moment.)

Answer (score 1):

A small observation is that: if $x \notin C \implies x \notin A\cap C$ because $A\cap C \subseteq C$. Using this you can justify the step above.